# Salesforce Ant - Deployment for Process Builder

Tags: ant

Added following snippet to you src/package.xml

```
   <!--TO_REMOVED-->
   <types>
     <members>My_Flow-33</members> 
     <name>Flow </name>
   </types>
   <!--TO_DELETE-->
```

Use following ant code

```
<target name="flowRequired">
    <condition property="includeFlow">
        <equals arg1="${deployFlow}" arg2="true"/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="deployFlow" unless="includeFlow"  depends="flowRequired">
    <replace file="src/package.xml">
        <replacefilter value="" token="TO_REMOVED--"/>
    </replace>        
    <replace file="src/package.xml">
        <replacefilter value="" token="!--TO_DELETE"/>
    </replace> 
</target>
```

I added the above snippet but my code in package.xml always gets commented Can anyone let me know as for what scenario the contents in the package.xml willl get deploy. The contents between To_Removed and To_delete My_Flow-33 Flow

Please help

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: ok I am trying to deploy Process builder using CICD process. Continuous Integration Continus Deployment. The thing happening is whenever we deploy process builders we get the error of overwriting the same version. Hence I was trying to trick deployment of the process builder as the process builder must be deployed only when needed

Comment: Hi @YogeshPatil, you have a whitespace in your name tag try `<name>Flow</name>` instead of  `<name>Flow </name>`

Comment: Hi @AkramG tried the thing but same results

Comment: Is there some way by which we can deactivate process builder using ant?